# Holding ASCII values 32-126 as an object or through a for loop in Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, ascii

I'm trying to have all the ASCII characters from 32-126 held as an object in java. Is there a way to hold them through a for loop in Java instead of writing all of them out?

ex.
String characters = "abcdefg";
etc.

Comment: Yes.  Remember that `char`s are just small integers, so you can write `for(char ch = 32; ch <= 126; ++ch)  carr[ch-32] = ch;` (`carr` being, of course, a previously declared `char[]`

Comment: @Kevin I would write that as an answer. I wasn't sure what the OP's confusion was about but this may well be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that chars are just small integers, so you can use a `char` as an index variable in a loop.  There are several possible ways to go about this.

Here's one that gives a `char[]` result:

```
char[] carr = new char[95]; // 95 = 126-32+1
for(char ch = 32; ch <= 126; ++ch) 
    carr[ch-32] = ch;
// for a `String` result, add the following line:
String printableAscii = new String(carr);
```

Here's another way, that ends up with a `String` result:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch = 32; ch <= 126; ++ch)
    sb.append(ch);
String printableAscii = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Note: This is possible because ASCII characters 0-127 are the same as Unicode characters 0-127 and UTF-16 encodes Unicode characters 0-127 with one UTF-16 code unit (Java `char`).